# How to create an instance by reading type from pointer

Tags: go

Suppose I declared a variable of type float like bellow

```
var meters float64
```

And taking user input and population that variable by bellow code

```
fmt.Scan(&meters)
```

using `reflect` it is possible for `Scan` method to know the type(`float64`) of the variable this pointer is pointing to. But how it is creating the instance of `float64` after reading user input?

Comment: Look for `reflect.New`

Comment: You can check the [source code](https://golang.org/src/fmt/scan.go).

Comment: It is possible using reflection, but there is no need in the above example. The passed pointer points to an already allocated value being the `meters` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not creating an *instance* of `float64`. The instruction `var meters float64` is creating the variable and thus the placeholder. We pass the address of the variable to fill from the stdin input.

Scan determines the type of the `Scan` variable and converts the input. This is performed in the function `scanOne` (line 944) in the file https://golang.org/src/fmt/scan.go.